# finding percentage based on user value and total users

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what I want to do.

I have a database with x amount of users

Each user has a value associated with it that can grow indefinitely (no end). As each user does more on my site the higher the value goes. It's very similar to stacks system in rating a user reputation and saying `top 5% of users`.

I want to take the users value based on all the other users value and total users and come up with a percentage that I can determine is that users x% of activity based on all users.

Here some sample

```
User1 Activity = 2345
User2 Activity = 34
User3 Activity = 12387
User4 Activity = 324
```

So I have a activity value for each user, a total activity score of 15090 (all values added together) and 4 users total.

I want to be able to say

```
User1 is x% of total users
User2 is x% of total users... and so on.
```

What would be the calculation to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user1 it is just $\frac {2345}{15090}\approx 0.1554=15.54\%$

Answer (score 1):

Use -

$$\frac{\text{UserN Activity Value}}{Total} × 100$$

Where N is natural number.